# Get An Image URI from a web URL

Tags: android, uri

I am using Glide to load the image from an URL into the ImageView. I want to get an ImageURI from the image URL.I am able to generate a normal URI. But Whenever i pass this URI into the WallpaperManager getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent the app crashes.

This is the stacktrace :-

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Image URI must be of the content scheme type
       at android.app.WallpaperManager.getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent(WallpaperManager.java:660)
       at backdoorstudio.polywallpapers.activity.MainActivity$1.onLongClick(MainActivity.java:138)
       at backdoorstudio.polywallpapers.adapters.GalleryAdapter$RecyclerTouchListener$1.onLongPress(GalleryAdapter.java:138)
       at android.view.GestureDetector.dispatchLongPress(GestureDetector.java:690)
       at android.view.GestureDetector.access$200(GestureDetector.java:37)
       at android.view.GestureDetector$GestureHandler.handleMessage(GestureDetector.java:266)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5234)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:70
```

Here Is My Code To Get The URI :-

```
URL url = new URL(image.getLarge());  //     http://www.example.com/image_large.png
URI uri = url.toURI();
```